# HOWTO find out what file versions a given version of docker-compose supports

Tags: docker-compose, version

How can I find out what file format versions (3.1? 3.2? ... 3.9? etc.) the version of `docker-compose` I am running (docker-compose version 1.20.0-rc2, build 8c4af54) supports?

Is there a better way than trial and error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table currently lives [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/), but the key is the `docker` version, not `docker-compose` version. E.g. 3.2 is support by `17.04.0` and greater